# Search through array of objects for case-insensitive partial match and sort results alphabetically

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I hope someone will be able to help me or at least guide me on what topics to look for answers

I'm newbie at React. I have a code that allows me to filter the list that is in the items object. And there's no problem with that. But I would like to use prepared json file instead, but when I try to refer to "city" I get a bug at the onTextChanged method (Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined). I'm not exactly sure how I should relate to next levels in json. I tried something like that if we take the CityList  as a definition of items.

```
this.items.city.sort().filter(...)
```

This is the whole component

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import "./HiddenTownList.css";
    //import CityList from "./JsonCities";

    class HiddenTownList extends Component {
        items = [
            "Warsaw",
            "New York",
            "London"
        ];
        state = {
            suggestion: []
        };

        onTextChanged = (e) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            let suggestion = [];
            if (value.length > 0) {
                const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i');
                suggestion = this.items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
                this.setState(() => ({ suggestion }))
            }
            else {
                this.setState(() => ({ suggestion }));
            }
        }

        renderSuggestions() {
            const { suggestion } = this.state;
            if (suggestion.length === 0) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return (
                    <ul>{suggestion.map((city) => <li>{city}</li>)}</ul>
                )

            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <input onChange={this.onTextChanged}></input>
                    {this.renderSuggestions()}
                </>
            )
        }

    };
    export default HiddenTownList;
```

JSON code sample

```
const CityList = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "city": "Katowice",
        "lat": "50.258415",
        "lng": "19.027545",
        "country": "Poland",
        "admin": "Śląskie"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "city": "Warsaw",
        "lat": "52.25",
        "lng": "21",
        "country": "Poland",
        "admin": "Mazowieckie"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "city": "Łódź",
        "lat": "51.75",
        "lng": "19.466667",
        "country": "Poland",
        "admin": "Łódzkie"
    }]
```

Comment: It tries to call the sort() method on a variable which is undefined at this time. are you sure that value is passing properly? Did you try to console.log() and seen the value?

Comment: How do you refer to the city? In your sample it's doesn't referred.

Comment: I changed the sample data from the "items" because they could be confusing

@AbuSufian when I try to show the data on the screen using the map method it all works fine, I tried to test the console.log and debugger to track the data. The problem is that I can't refer to lower json levels of data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform sort function on city. Which is variable. Thats way it is giving undefined value. Sort always work on array field.